# Where are the setup files or installed files on Kubernetes. Where are these installed on Linux or Google Cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have used Kubernetes and I deployed for example WordPress or nginx or etc. We install from the YAML file. Where is it installed how can i find directory of pages(for example WordPress pages etc.) at same point at Google Cloud too. When I use Kubernetes at Google Cloud where is the path of installed files(ex. index.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the docker image **directly** without attaching anything like NFS, S3 or Disk then you will be able to get those files by default in the container file system(index.php and all).

With any **K8s** cluster you check files inside **container** either Gcloud or any :

```
kubectl get pods

kubectl exec -it <Wordpress pod name> -- /bin/bash
```

If you are attaching the File system like **NFS**, or object storage **S3** or **EFS** you will be able to watch those files there unless you mount and apply config using the **YAML** file.

Regarding setup file (**YAML**),

Kubernetes uses the **ETCD** database as a data store. The flow is like this. **Kubectl** command connect to **API server** and sends the YAML file to API server. API parses and store the information in ETCD database so you wont be getting those file as it is in YAML format.

Comment: Do not try to edit files in the `kubectl exec` shell!  Particularly in an environment like GKE it's possible for a pod to get deleted and recreated outside your control, and any changes you make there will be lost.

Comment: thx @DavidMaze if i want to change then we should use volume i know somethings generally about docker and kubernetes  but i wondered where is files stored. Harsh Manvar notably thanks for codes. i pushed to this answer useful but i dont have 15 reputation :) thanks again.